# Erro em código de decriptografia usando vb.net!

Tags: vb.net, algoritmo, criptografia

Estou com problemas para descriptografar com o código abaixo que achei na net:

[image: Código de Encriptação e Descriptação com VB.net]
[image: Criptografa]

Ao depurar é possível ver que na propriedade `TripleDES.Key` tem o valor 16 em `length` e o `Buffer` 15, é por esse motivo? Como resolver?

**Não entendo nada de criptografia, peguei esse código na internet.**
[image: Descriptografa]

Comment: Esse Buffer foi encriptado como? Com a função `Criptografa` acima? O fato do CT ter tamanho diferente da chave não é problema, mas ainda assim é bem estranho um CT de 15 bytes... Talvez tenha faltado um *padding*, não sei. (P.S. nunca, **nunca** use ECB na prática, é terrivelmente inseguro! Use um modo de encriptação autenticada como o GCM, CCM, etc, ou na falta disso CBC ou CTR junto com um MAC. E 3DES não é ruim, mas AES dá mais segurança, se possível use isso. Por fim, esse método de derivação de chave - MD5 de uma senha - não é nada bom, sugiro o PBKDF2 em vez disso).

Comment: Obrigado pelos conselhos.
 foi criptografado pelo método acima sim.
Eu detectei o problema, acontece que ao criptografar nesse meu projetinho asp.net, está salvando apenas 20 caracteres, e o código criptografado tem mais de 20 caracteres. não importa o tamanho da senha que eu digite, sempre salva 20 caracteres no banco. E não é isso que acontece na minha outra aplicação com o mesmo código em windows form. 

Só não consegui achar o porque disso. Sendo que minha coluna no banco é de 200 caracteres.

Comment: Cod criptografado na aplicação windows form JFYVJVDep2yzpc2ky/wnXA==............................................E o Cod gerado na aplicação webform JFYVJVDep2yzpc2ky/wn

Comment: Poderia postar o código invés de imagens? É muito ruim visualizar essas imagens em dispositivos de tela menor.

Comment: Concordo com o @re22, e além disso fica mais difícil testar seu código se não podemos copiar e colar (como imagem, só nos resta digitar tudo de novo...)

Comment: Muito provavelmente é um problema de *padding* mesmo. Veja [esse teste no ideone](https://ideone.com/1x4agv): tentei decriptar o código correto e ele deu "*padding* inválido". Isso significa que o *padding* padrão que o .Net está usando é diferente do *padding* usado pela sua aplicação original. Procure descobrir qual é esse *padding*. (P.S. Se não for problema de *padding*, é problema de *encoding*. Sua string original tinha acentos? [Esse outro teste](https://ideone.com/jsWQFZ) encriptou e decriptou corretamente, usando só ASCII).

Comment: Galera consegui corrigir, o problema estava na minha procedure, a variavel @senha estava setada como varchar de 20, por isso salva-vá apenas 20 caracteres. 
Coisa boba mais que rendeu um tempo aqui kkk.
Obrigado a quem se dispôs a me ajudar!!